# Backlight settings not stored

Tags: laptop, samsung, acpi, backlight

Recently bought a new laptop (Samsung 700Z) and installed ubuntu 12.04. Most stuff works out of the box, but some details are driving me crazy. I installed the fglrx driver to shut down the fans and also the samsung-tools, so I can change the fan behaviour. But:

Keys for the keyboard backlight do not work also they are mapped in /lib/udev/rules.d/95-keymap.rules.
The cd ejection key does not work.
Keyboard and screen backlight settings are not stored, so after each reboot, suspend and even screen locks both backlights are set to maximum.

Using acpi_backlight=vendor in grub does not fix that behaviour, it makes it even worse: I cannot set the screen backlight to high values, just about to 30 percent of the possible max. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: making the eject key work should be really easy. Go to 'System Settings' -> 'Keyboard' -> 'Shortcuts'. In the tab Sound & Media there should be an entry 'eject' just click on it and press your eject button.

Comment: There is the correct key added. Seems that the problem was a corrupt dvd.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got it to work. I had to write various scripts and wrote the story down here: http://blog.christian-hufgard.de/keyboardscreen_backlight_settings_ubuntu_12_04-2012-07-30

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

In most laptops now a days those settings won't get stored. Its because of different hybrid solutions and proprietary graphics drivers. Follow  the followings to set it to moderate brightness at start up.

Try following for paths shown by `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` and replace accordingly.

example paths will be like

```
/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

1. For the above path Get the maximum brightness:

`cat  /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness`

Try a lower value to set the brightness, say output is 16 so I will try with half of it

`echo 8 | sudo tee  /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

If there are more than one path, repeat the above steps to see which one gives you more flexibility.

**If this works**,  make this happen in each login automatically by doing the following

`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

Enter this line just before `exit 0`. It should look like

```
echo YOUR_VALUE_HERE > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
exit 0
```

Comment: As far as I know, rc.local is only called during startup. I added a script under pm-utils/sleep.d and this was executed during resume. But even this does not resolve the problem that a locking of the screen sets all values to maximum. :(